# Three.js wireframe option not working with MeshBasicMaterial

Tags: three.js, wireframe

I'm using .stl file. For some files it worked perfect but for some it doesn't.

Here is the code.

Any solution??

Thanks in advance.

---

```
`material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x009d28, opacity: 1.0, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 1.0, transparent: true } );`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: i mean, the object is showing perfect but wireframe option not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you provide a live link?